# Getting NextVal from sequence in Visual Studio SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert into table using next value from sequence. This is causing an error in `LocalDB` of Visual Studio but works in SQL Developer.

```
insert into department (id_department, name, abbreviation, dept_head)
values (id_department_seq.nextval, 'School of Communications, Media, Arts and Design', department_abbreviation_seq.nextval, 'Nate Horowitz');
```

Getting this error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
>   The multi-part identifier "id_department_seq.nextval" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
>   The multi-part identifier "department_abbreviation_seq.nextval" could not be bound

Comment: The sequence is not defined in the database you are connected to.  You might try a 3-part name.

Comment: no i already defined sequence `create sequence id_department_seq
start with 1000 increment by 1
minvalue 1000 maxvalue 99999;`

Comment: Run this:  select * 
from sys.sequences
where name ='id_department_seq'  and if there is a result then you are not connwcting to the same db where you created the seq

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ so how to fix that

Comment: so what is the result of the query? is it found in sys.sequences table?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ gives me name,objectID,principal id,scheme id all kind of stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax for getting the next value for your sequence looks weird to me. I'm familiar with the following:

```
insert into department (id_department, name, abbreviation, dept_head)
    values (
        NEXT VALUE FOR id_department_seq, 
        'School of Communications, Media, Arts and Design', 
        NEXT VALUE FOR department_abbreviation_seq, 
        'Nate Horowitz'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks works still cant figure out why same code works in SQL developer but not in Visual Studio SQL database :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd prefer what I've got here given that it's ultimately going to be interpreted by the SQL engine, which allows you to not have to worry about what a given client (in this case VS) is doing for pre-processing. TL;DR - this is closer to the "bare metal" so it more likely to be applicable in more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your insert statement to ensure you have the sequence created.

```
if not exists(select * from sys.sequences where name ='id_department_seq') then
 begin
  create sequence id_department_seq start with 1000 increment by 1 minvalue 1000 maxvalue 99999;
end

insert into ....
```